# How to find walrasian asignations?

Tags: microeconomics, general-equilibrium, pure-exchange-economy

In a economy Arrow Debreau of pure exchange with two agents and two goods. With utility function of Leontief for agent B, where $U_b(x_b,y_b)=\min(x_b,y_b)$; and for agent A a simple Cobb-Douglas $U_a(x_a,y_a)=x_ay_a$ where the marginal rates of sustituion can´t be found because the concept of convergence can´t be applied. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What are the endowments? There are already a fair number of questions discussing Edgeworth Box problems for two agents with Cobb-Douglas and Leontief preferences respectively but none with exactly these parameters. You check them out and see if you are still confused.

Comment: Yes, I didn't see two specific questions that help with this problem.